# Postgis ST_DWithin function in laravel(lumen) query

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, postgis

I found an issue with postgis functions inside laravel(lumen) query builder.

Lumen version: 5.6

Postgres: 9.6.9 with postGIS

I have a code that works:

```
$sql = "ST_DWithin(location ,'POINT($lat $lon)', $distance)";
$query->whereRaw($sql);
```

This works but I'd like to pass parameters via parameter binding:

```
$sql = "ST_DWithin(location ,'POINT(? ?)', ?)";
$query->whereRaw($sql, [$lat, $lon, $distance]);
```

At first glance looks good, but it it returns an error:

`Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined (SQL: select * from "my_table" where ST_DWithin(location ,'POINT(123 123)', 1000)`

I tried other combinations and that works:

```
$point = 'POINT($lat $lon)';
$sql = "ST_DWithin(location ,?, ?)";
$query->whereRaw($sql, [$point, $distance]);
```

so the problem seems to be with the `POINT` function

Comment: cast to geometry: `'POINT(? ?)'::geometry`

Comment: it doesn't work. Stil the same error

Comment: other things I notice: 1) WKT defines coordinate order as in [x, y], thus you need to use `'POINT(<lon> <lat>)'` --> better use `SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(<lon>, <lat>), 4326)`; 2) latitiude cannot exceed `+-90°`; 3) if you intend to use meter as distance, cast both input geometries to *geography*, otherwise the distance parameter will be treated as *degrees*; 4) check if you have to escape your parameters in the string literal

Answer (score 0):

Here geometry should be passed as WKB not in WKT format.

```
select * from "my_table" where ST_DWithin(location ,ST_GeomFromText('POINT(123 123)') , 1000)
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: still the same error. I solved it using ST_MakePoint(?,?) instead of POINT(? ?) but I still don't know why previous query doesn't work. It looks like that laravel query builder/php PDO went crazy when was passed the parameter with '' sign

Comment: is that query running properly in postgresql?

Comment: yes, 
    select * from "my_table" where ST_DWithin(location ,'POINT(123 123)', 1000)
works in postgresql